# Making tiny objects visible for their location when zooming out

Tags: qgis, symbology, scale, zoom, generalization

I'm adding small features to QGIS that I need to be in a precise location (trail signs) like so:

**1:500**
[image]

However, when I zoom out, they become invisible:

**1:10000**
[image]

If I switch the sizing to millimetres (rather than meters at scale) then I have to move the sign as I zoom out to keep it from overlapping the trails, then the position is all out of whack when zoomed in.

So, how do I create a precise placement, but still make tiny objects visible for their location when I zoom out?

Comment: What scale is the first image, what scale the second? How do you plan to use this map?

Comment: When you say the "appropriate place", in fact you want it to physically change its real x-y location according to scale, in order to maintain visual distinction from the other features. You might be able to do this with a label (with variable placement according to scale) but I can't see how to do it with map a feature. Perhaps some of the power gurus will have a view.

Comment: @erik Added scale. Need to use for both field instruction (precise placement) as well as overview (general placement / count information).

Comment: @LeighBettenay I mean, ideally I don't want to change its x-y location at all, I just want it to visually be relevant both at scale as well as overview... The answer below (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381083/94812) does a creative blend of symbol / label combo... I'll play around with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to use rule based symbology to use two different symbol at big and small scale. This way you could have a properly positioned symbol at big scale and a non overlapping symbol at small scale by using a combination of small symbol and label.

In the picture below (view at small scale) I set a sign symbol from 0 to 1/5000 and a small black dot from 1/5000 and down. then I set a label with leader line using the same symbol and display the label only from 1/5000 and down. As you see you have the small black dot at the right position while the label show the right symbol with an offset. When you zoom-in past 1/5000 the label and black dot disappear and are replaced by the symbol at the right place

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In cartography, generalization is a commonly accepted practice, including displacement of objects, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_generalization#Displace

However, displacement should not be too large. You can achieve it like this:

Use an expression and data driven override for the postion of your marker. In the styling, you can define an offset of the x coordinate that is scale dependent: so the more you zoom out, the more the point shifts to the right. With the following expression, you have full control of the settings (how much the offset will be at which scale). You can manually tweak the numbers to get an optimal result (see below to understand the values):

```
array (
    scale_linear ( 
        @map_scale ,
        1, 
        10000000 ,
        0 ,
        5
    ) , 0
)
```

Explanation of the expression: The data driven override of x/y offset expects an array of offset-values for x and y values (coordinates) - this is only for visualization, the point keeps it's original position. Thus we set an array with `array (x,y)`. The value for y should be 0 (if you don't want to move it up/down), so the last number in the expression is 0. For x, we want to take the current scale of the map to use it for the amount the point is displaced. We can get it the scale with the variable `@map_scale`. Thus `array (@map_scale, 0)` theoretically would be enough.

But if you have a scale of [1:]1'000'000 that means that the x offset would be 1 million mm: 1 km away on (off) your screen, thus much too far away. That's why  we add `scale_linear(value,domain_min,domain_max,range_min,range_max)`. The input values (`@map_scale`) are thus scaled: from the map_scale of [1:]1 (min) to [1:]10000000 (max), the resulting values should be scaled linear to a value of 0 to 5 [mm on screen]. If your displacement should only start at a scale of let's say [1:]10000, replace the no. 1 in the expression with this value.

[image: qgis expression editor: scale dependent offset, scale linear]

[image: cartographic generalization displace point]

If you want to use it with a polygon and in the same time generalize it's form, you might do it like this: on the symbol layer for the actual polygon form, set a scale dependent visibility by activating the Enable symbol layer checkbox and setting an expression like this: `@map_scale < 8000`. Than add another symbol layer, choose geometry generator and create an offset with an expression like this:

```
translate ( centroid ($geometry), 
    scale_linear ( 
        @map_scale ,
        10000, 
        10000000 ,
        10 ,
        30000
    ) , 0)
```

Set a simple rectangle as marker and again set a scale dependent visibility by activating the Enable symbol layer checkbox and defining this time: `@map_scale > 8000` - so for a scale up tp 1:8000 you see the actual geometry, when zooming out more, you will only see the simplified marker that is slightly shifted so as not to cover the street.

[image: qgis expression editor: translate scale dependent]

See here how that works in an interactive visualization with the settings from above:
https://qgiscloud.com/daur/offset/

[image: qgis cartographic generalization]