# Moving labels with moving features

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

This is a question/problem which arised from another issue: [Assigning specific feature in expression builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466634/assigning-specific-feature-in-expression-builder/466730#466730)

I´ve adjusted for features to be moved according to how the scale is changed, but I would also like the labels to follow the moved features.

I've tried a few different ways, among all this one which doesn't do anything.

[image]

I've chosen the position to be "exact from the point" and thereafter I've tried the code as follows:

```
if( attribute(@feature, 'name') = 'Langmyr 7', array ( scale_linear ( @map_scale , 2000, 10000 , 0 , 10 ) , scale_linear ( @map_scale , 2000, 10000 , 0 , 15 )), array(0,0) )
```

But as you can see, it's only the features themselfs who are moving.

[image] [image]

Comment: The Council of Cartographers frowns upon your heretic deeds and forbids you to name the product "map". That being said: Your actual features do not move, only their display on the map does - and your call-out lines are anchored to the actual features, not the place they are displayed at. Try adding you expression for moving the displayed symbols as input for the data-defined placement of the call-out lines.

Comment: It was not my intention to make anyone frown, especially not The Council of Cartographers. However, when I, for whatever reason, do a heretic deed then I'm willingly trying to amend the issue, but in this case I can not see where I have named the product "map" (except for in the code expression, which I doubt that I can do anything about). 
Thank you for letting me know, I have tried to solve it that way as well but without any success.

Comment: Try using the same expression in the `geometry generator` box of the `placement` tab

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but I'll get the info "The expression is not geometry" by doing that.

Comment: ah yes, add `affine_transform` to it then to apply the offset

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but I've now tried to add ´affine_transform´ in front of the expression in the ´geometry generator` without any success.

Comment: Hey @Niklas, for somebody to find your question, it might help to edit the title to "Moving labels with _moving_ features". Have you tried to use "Datadefinierat" and insert into the code for the label the code of the movement of the feature points?

Comment: Hey @HeyGeorge! That's a good idea and I've now changed it, thank you for the suggestion. Yes I have tried with the same code in "data defined" for both coordinates and point in the "placement" settings as well as "data defined placing" in the "symbol line" setting, but without any success.