# ID expression links to the wrong feature

Tags: qgis, expression

This is a question/problem which arised from another issue: [Assigning specific feature in expression builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466634/assigning-specific-feature-in-expression-builder/466730#466730).

The ID in the code does not seem to correspond with the right feature.

Here's an example of how I've used ID nr. 1 and 2 in the code but the features with ID nr. 2 and 3 are the ones who are moving:

```
if( array_contains(array(1,2),@id),array ( scale_linear ( @map_scale , 3000, 10000 , 0 , -5 ) , scale_linear ( @map_scale , 3000, 10000 , 0 , 5 )),array(0,0) )
```

[image: Example of moving the wrong feature]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@id` is the internal ID of the feature, so depending on the storage type (and primary key definition) of the layer, it may be completely unrelated to the value of the field that happens to be called `id`

Comment: The problem was solved by just removing @. Thank you!