# Using scale in QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, expression, scale

This is a question/problem which arised from another issue: [Assigning specific feature in expression builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466634/assigning-specific-feature-in-expression-builder/466730#466730).

I've managed to use expression builder in order to move features according to the change of scale, though after a certain scale I would like the movement to stop and I can not seem to get that right.

The code which I've used (with the aim of stopping the movement at a scale 1:10000) is as follows:

```
if( 
    array_contains (array(1,2),@id),
    array(
        scale_linear (@map_scale , 3000, 10000 , 0 , -5),
        scale_linear (@map_scale , 3000, 10000 , 0 , 5)
    ),
    array (0,0)
)
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking when you say you "would like the movement to stop". As it stands, your code will have no shift of points 1 & 2 at a scale of 1:3000 or larger, and a shift of [-5,5] (mm?) at 1:10000 or smaller, with linear scaling in between. Maybe edit the question so it's clear what the problem is that you are trying to solve.